# I think that my question, in its final form, is not too broad - Updated

Tags: discussion

[A world where every individual naturally desires to achieve something "profoundly incredible"?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/37100/a-world-where-every-individual-naturally-desires-to-achieve-something-profoundl)

I think I've fixed the question to be focused enough now.

Comment: For me, you have now reached a situation where it is a bit unclear what you are looking for.  A question "how does such a world look like" is always too broad. A "world" encompasses many different aspects. I think you could maybe focus your question on whether it is possible to motivate everyone. So think about clarifying what you expect of answers.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin I seriously doubt it is possible to motivate everyone. I think I understand what you're saying about that part still being too broad. I will try to fix that in the morning. Ill change "What would it look like" to "what advantages and disadvantages would such a society have?". Ill wait and see what else is suggested.

Comment: That's already something. And now, if you could add something like "What advantages [..] in term of [economics/military/scientific/... <- pick one or two]", you'd get a very interesting question :)

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin done.

Comment: You make a solid argument. Nominated for reopening.